# Property update UI control

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have a main window with a text box where the focus is binded to a property, this is the xmal:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay" x:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding TxtFocused, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In my main window view model I can change the value of the boolean property TxtFocused, and it will put the text box focused or not depending on its value.

I then have a sub window, with its own view model, on that view model I have access to the main window view model. When closing this window, in the sub window view model, I access the property TxtFocused of the main window view model, and set it to true.

My problem is that even if the property TxtFocused is set to true, in my main window the text box doesn't have the focus.

I know how I can work around this, but it very ugly, and it would violate WPF/MVC rules, since im trying to keep the UI elements far from the view models.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

My sub window appears over the main window, not changing its visibility, can that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Activated` event of the MainWindow and there set it to true.